# Version list for TOPS-10?

Tags: operating-system, mainframe, pdp-10

So, does anybody have a list of TOPS-10 versions? I haven't been able to find any information aside from versions 7.03, and 7.04. are these lost to time?

To clarify, I'm not asking for the software, just a list of versions, maybe an old catalog or something.

Anybody got info? I apologize if this is the wrong type of question.

EDIT: thank you for the responses, I haven't found a single list with all of them, but I've found a lot of bits an pieces. Now that I've got the proper terminology for previous versions, I can search a lot easier. Mostly it's just stuff on bitsavers mirrors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Phil Budne’s list of TOPS-10 versions](http://www.ultimate.com/phil/pdp10/tops-10) is the most comprehensive list I’m aware of, from TOPS-10 5.01 in 1970 (the first release with the “TOPS-10” name) to 7.0 releases with uncertain version numbers in 1990. Before 5.01 it was called the “Monitor” (PDP-6 Monitor on the PDP-6, then PDP-10 Monitor on the PDP-10), and some of those releases are included in Phil’s list too.

Comment: Oooohhhh, so the earlier versions weren't called TOPS-10? Any idea what they were called

Comment: TOPS-10 was simply called the PDP-6 / PDP-10 Monitor or Timesharing Monitor before being rebranded.

Comment: I came in at 5.07 on a KI when my university acquired a -10 for undergraduate use, and it was definitely TOPS-10 (and DECsystem-10) then.

Comment: Even after the **operating system** was named TOPS-10, the **kernel** remained known as the monitor.  I definitely owned a "monitor calls" manual. From manuals such as [this one](http://bitsavers.org/pdf/dec/pdp10/Monitor/DEC-10-NGCB-D_PDP-10_Systems_Users_Guide_Aug68.pdf), it looks like the operating system had no name beyond "PDP-10 system".  Note on page INTRO-2 that the monitor is a mere part of the system.

Comment: This list is less complete, but it's interesting because these are versions actually preserved.  http://sky-visions.com/dec/tops10.shtml